# How many ways can 10 identical buttons, 10 identical bows, and 10 identical beads be distributed to 4 different people?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

**Question:** How many ways can 10 identical buttons, 10 identical bows, and 10 identical beads be distributed to 4 different people?

**My thoughts:** I decided to use the *bars and stars* method. With the knowledge that there are 4 unique groups of people, each person has the possibility of getting 1 of the 10 buttons, 1 of the 10 bows, and 10 of the 10 bows. I'm having trouble deciding whether the items are the elements or the actual people are the elements (the *stars* in this case). Your thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count how many ways there are to distribute $10$ identical buttons between the four people.

Separately count how many ways there are to distribute $10$ identical bows between the four people.

Separately count how many ways there are to distribute $10$ identical beads between the four people.

Apply multiplication principle.

Comment: After reading it from another person, I'm confident the answer is correct. I wasn't sure if I was thinking correctly when I decided to do \binom{13}{10} = 286 and taking the result and raising it by 3. 286^{3} = 23393656. Thanks!